# When converting PDFs to JPEGs, how do I prevent characters with french accents from disappearing?

Tags: pdf, jpeg, ghostscript

When I use Ghostscript to convert a PDF containing french characters to a JPEG, some of characters with accents disappear in the output JPEG. What seems to be causing this problem? How can I fix it?

I’m attaching before and after screenshots to illustrate this, the debug logs, and a link to input file, and the specific command I ran.

Command:

```
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -dDEBUG -dNOPAUSE -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 \
   -sOutputFile=./out-1.jpg -dJPEGQ=100 -r300 corde_a_linge.pdf -c quit
```

before/after screenshots:

- https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mtia9a993cwwvan/AAADVHe3WQv9ArZTTDMRJRGaa?dl=0

Input PDF:

- http://pouremporter.communagir.org/medias/2014/09/corde_a_linge.pdf

Debug logs:

- https://gist.github.com/dmlicht/c1a6a9eb02c2d6384b94

Version: GPL Ghostscript 9.15 (2014-09-22)

OS: OSX Yosemite Version 10.10.1

Please let me know if theres any more information I can provide.

Comment: I don't see this result with any version of Ghostscript currently available to me. I'm travelling at the moment so I don't have any access to a Mac, I'll try and see if I can borrow one tomorrow. In the meantime, where did you get the Ghostscript binary you are using ? Did you build it from source ?

Comment: One of my colleagues tried this on a Mac with both the current master code and teh 9.15 release and the file worked well in both cases. Without knowing where you sourced your copy of Ghostscript my suggestion would be that you get the current source and rebuild it yourself.

Comment: There might be some issue with that font.

Comment: All the fonts are embedded in the PDF file, this was my first thought, that font substitution was taking place, but that seems not to be the case.

Comment: Hi KenS and user3344003, first off thanks a lot for your help! I installed Ghostscript using Homebrew.

Comment: Same problem on Red Hat 7 with GhostScript version 9.07 when converting from pdf to png.

Comment: Got the same problem with GhostScript 9.16 from MacPorts on Yosemite.

Answer (score 2):

I did run the exact same command as in your question, albeit on a Mavericks system.

- The left result is from Ghostscript 9.10 (as distributed via the MacPorts folks).
- The right result is via a "self-compiled from current Git sources" Ghostscript 9.16 GIT PRERELEASE:

  ---

  [image][image]
  <sub>(Right-click images to *'open in new tab'* and you may see images in original size.)</sub>

  ---

So clearly, somewhere on the way between 9.10 (or 9.15 if we take into account your result) and current Git source code there must have happened some sort of fix to this problem.

I cannot debug further right now. Maybe KenS can contribute more thoughts once he's back from travelling.

---

### Update:

Here is some more info.

**FreeType used by MacPorts installation**

```
kp@mbp:>  otool -L /opt/local/bin/gs
/opt/local/bin/gs:
  /opt/local/lib/libgs.9.10.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
  /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)

kp@mbp:>  otool -L /opt/local/lib/libgs.9.10.dylib | grep -i freetype
  /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.1.0)
```

**FreeType used by "self-compiled-from-Git" installation**

```
kp@mbp:>  otool -L /usr/local/bin/gs | grep -i freetype
 /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.2.0)

kp@mbp:> ls -l /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  1143056 12 Aug  2014 /opt/X11/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  1099796  6 Jan 13:28 /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
```

So indeed, the suspicion about FreeType being the cause has some justification!

Comment: I had a quick discuss with the other developers and all we can come up with is, possibly, a broken shared FreeType library. We are, of course, using the Ghostscript tree and compiling from source, not using MacPorts, our suspicion is that its something to do with the MacPorts compiled version, but we don't really know what, and aren't in a position to debug that. I'd still suggest compiling from our sources.

Comment: The conversion worked after uninstalling the Homebrew version and building from the directory hosted here: http://ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html Thank you so much for the help